# Sending data with Multiple-File-Upload

Tags: javascript

Im using the Multiple-File-Upload from [hayaGeek](http://hayageek.com/jquery-multiple-file-upload/). The normal upload is working fine, but now i have to send some data together with the file that the php script knows where to store the file. There is the formData option to send data, but whatever i try, the data are not sent. Only if i add the data as GET data to the url, they arrive the php script. Until now i was able to build up the script with php, so that i could add the GET data before sending the file to the client. But now i build a new version of our website and then i have to take the data from two form fields, that are filled before by an ajax script.

```
function initUpl(){
    var pid = $('#nppidsuche').val();
    var np = $('#npanzahl').val();
    $("#multipleupload").uploadFile({
        url:"file-upload_np.php",
        method: "POST",
        returnType:"json",
        formData:{np_pruefnr: pid, nachpruefung: np},
        multiple:true,
        fileName:"myfile",
        allowedTypes:"jpg,jpeg,png,pdf,txt,doc,docx,tif,edoc,asice",
        showDelete:false
    });
}
```

This function is called after the form fields are filled. I also tried to read the fields directly in the formData option and even hard coded data are ignored.

Does anybody the the error and how can i use the data from the form fields?

Comment: What are the extra variables you want sent ? which one is the file ? how are accessing the info in the server?

Comment: pid and np are only numbers. They are taken from the php file on the server as get or post data. With this configuration they should be post data, but i tried get too.

Comment: how are you accessing those variables in your php file ?

Comment: Like any other post data.
$np_pruefnr = $_POST['pid'];
$nachpruefung = $_POST['nachpruefung'];

Comment: First error. the pid is sent from client like np_pruefnr so ro receive you should use like $_POST['np_pruefnr']. Could you check also in your developer tools how the form data is sent in the network tab ? a upload that picture ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. The problem was indeed the wrong data name pid, With np_pruefnr its working fine.

Comment: Nice to hear it ! Good luck!